# Is it possible in Git to only stage files that are staged and modified?

Tags: git

Is it possible in Git to only stage files that have already been staged, but have been modified since?

For example, given:

```
> git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   file1
        modified:   file2

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   file2
        modified:   file3
```

Is it possible to tell Git to only stage `file2` without specifying `file2` (e.g. not `git add file2` or something similar)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking beyond `git add`, you can do:

```
git update-index --again
```

From the docs:

> Runs `git update-index` itself on the paths whose index entries are different from those from the `HEAD` commit.

which, as it turns out, is exactly what we need here.

Comment: Perfect. Another one for alias: `restage = update-index --again`

Comment: @neverendingqs - yeah, thats useful :)